# Conceptual probability question?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, problem-solving

I will illustrate my question with an example. Suppose we're trying to solve this problem:

> Bob possesses a coin which has a probability of $\dfrac 14$ of turning up $T$ and a probability of $\dfrac 34$ of turning up $H$, and the flips are independent of each other. Bob performs the experiment of the flipping the coin until the first head shows up, and then stops and records the number of flips he did. What is the probability that it took Bob $3$ flips to get the first head?

This is the way I've been taught to do this sort of problem: The sample space is $\{H, TH, TTH, TTTH,  ... \}$. We want to find $$P[(\text{first flip, T})\cap (\text{second flip, T})\cap(\text{third flip, H}) ]$$

$$= P[(\text{first flip, T})]\cdot P[(\text{second flip, T})] \cdot P[(\text{third flip, H})]$$

$$= \dfrac 14 \cdot \dfrac 14  \cdot \dfrac34$$

My question is, is the probability (for example) $P[(\text{second flip, T})]$ really equal to $\dfrac 14$? What if the experiment ends on the first flip? Then I would think $P[(\text{second flip, T})]=0$ or undefined. So instead of calculating

$$P[(\text{first flip, T})\cap (\text{second flip, T})\cap(\text{third flip, H}) ]$$

shouldn't we be calculating something like

$$P[((\text{first flip, T})\cap(\text{experiment lasts at least 2 flips }))$$

$$\cap ((\text{second flip, T})\cap(\text{experiment lasts at least 3 flips }))$$

$$  \cap((\text{third flip, H})\cap (\text{experiment lasts at least 3 flips}))]$$

?

Comment: A mathematician's answer is: set the experiment to involve an infinite number of flips regardless of how things go, and ask for "what is the probability that the first head was on the 3rd or later flip?" This approach does not use your sample space, instead it uses the space of all flip sequences. A more real-world answer is to use conditional probability: the probability that it took exactly 3 flips is the probability that it took at least two flips times the probability that it took exactly 3 flips conditioned on it taking at least two flips.

Comment: @Ian So in the way I did set up the question, am I right that we should be calculating the probability I wrote at the bottom of the OP?

Comment: It's not exactly that, it's $P(N=3)=P(N=3 \mid N>2)P(N>2)=P(N=3 \mid N>2)P(N>2 \mid N>1)P(N>1)$. Now each of those three factors is a "single experiment" quantity and you are giving your assumptions about the number of flips taken *explicitly* in how you do the conditioning, rather than *implicitly* as in your description. That is, it does not strictly speaking make sense to say "the probability that the third flip goes heads" if a third flip didn't always happen. But it does make sense to ask for "the probability that the third flip goes heads, conditioned on there being a third flip at all".

Comment: If you are still interested or curious about this kind of distribution, see [the Geometric Distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I had to remove the comment because it got messed up somehow. I am starting to wonder why it's usually not taught this way, it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Ian Here is the last comment reposted: I'm not sure I understood the explanation but I think I understood the math. You did $P[N=3]=P[(N=3) \cap( N>2)] = P[N=3|N>2] \cdot P[N>2] =  P[N=3|N>2] \cdot P[(N>2) \cap (N>1)] = P[N=3|N>2] \cdot P[N>2|N>1] \cdot P[N>1].$  ...

Comment: ...Now we can calculate each piece. The first factor is $\dfrac 34$, the second is $\dfrac 14$, and the last is $\dfrac 14$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I think the reason this approach isn't usually taught is because it is more versatile and still correct to consider the sample space to be *all* sequences of coin flips and then filter out the sequences that matter from that.

Comment: @Ian Thank you very very much for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, I think it is easier and clearer to view this as a tree.

The point is that after a head, and after the third tail in a row, it does not matter what happens next. Your calculation is not going to be affected.

[image: Probability Tree]

If you look at the nodes, there are 4 of relevance (as you noted), with probabilities of 3/4, 3/16, 3/64, 1/64. Obviously, these add up to 1, because one of these must occur. Areas that are further down the tree are not going to matter, because the probability at each node is the sum of the probability of all the nodes further down the tree from there.

Aside: This is too easy to solve with Markov chains, but Markov chains would be the right way to solve the harder versions of it...